# web.config error - webm, ttf, ogv

Tags: asp.net, web-config, mime

I am having issues adding extensions to the web.config file.
I made it because it was returning webm files with a 404 error despite being on there.

when I upload this to the root folder of my godaddy hosted server, it gives me an error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Is it returning an error because it is poorly formatted or why else?

thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".ttf"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".eot"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="pplication/x-font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
    </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: No, it gives you an error because file is not allowed to be served as you indicated.

Comment: @leppie hi leppie, thanks. any ideas how to fix it so the error doesn't occur